# My wordpress permalink structure is not working like i want it

Tags: wordpress, url, permalinks

i have some problems with my permalink structure on my wordpress website.

i want that my URL structure looks like this:

www.website.com

`www.website.com/about-me` <- page 
`www.website.com/analyze` <- category
`www.website.com/analyze/2` <- page 2 of my category analyze
`www.website.com/analyze/trump-vs-clinton` <- article of the category analyze

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

In the Custom Structure option, input `%category%/%postname%`.

Here's a [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) to the Wordpress Codex on Using Permalinks. It'll give you many more options, should you decide to need them.

Comment: That's the problem!
I used this permalink structure and not all of my postet link work. 

With this structure
www.website.com - works!

www.website.com/about-me - (page) works!

www.website.com/analyze - (category) works! 

www.website.com/analyze/trump-vs-clinton (article of category analyze) works!

www.website.com/analyze/page/2 - (page two of my category) - doesnt work. 404! 

I also want to remove PAGE from the url analyze/page/2. it should look like this -> analyze/2